# How to split this phone number string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like `12860000005` in my javascript function. I need to split it like this `1-286-000-0005` and then show it in Confirm box.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
var string = 12860000005;
//expected result i want 1-286-000-0005
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regular expression

```
$(".phNum").text(function(i, text) {
        text = text.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3-$4");
        return text;
    });
```

Comment: If you are adding it to an input field, you should add `text.replace(/[^\d]/g, "")` to remove `-` and other characters from string if already present. This will make the function work for partially formatted strings also.